# Why was the minimum bounty doubled on another question?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty of amount 50 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files). After I awarded it, I tried to set another bounty on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613401/how-can-i-send-keys-to-inactive-directx-epsxe-window), but I found that the minimum amount I can offer is 100. I know that according to [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)  "if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty", but this is a **different** question not the same one. Why did this happen?

Note: I had less than 1,000 reputation when I set the first one, and more than 1,000 for the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum bounty is always doubled to 100 on questions where you've provided an answer yourself, which you've done on that question – even if the answer is subsequently deleted.

Comment: Where is this rule mentioned?

Comment: It's the bullet point directly above the one you read about doubling each additional bounty.